# Angularjs 1: delete an item, but item still exist until refresh

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

Here is my [simple angular 1 app](http://contactlist.shopshop.space).

[Source code](https://github.com/kenpeter/mean_contact_list) here.

Basically it is a [copy of this](https://github.com/chrisckchang/mean-contactlist).

I am able to do CRUD operations. The issue is that, when I delete a record. It redirects back to the home page. The record I deleted is still here. If I refresh the page, it is gone.

Is it a way to delete a record and then after redirect, I should see the latest list?

**Update 1:**

Unfortunately, it is still unresolved. Something strange that it seems the `promise` in `resolve` is cached. I added a few console.log inside the code. You can see the code flow. Open chrome developer tool to see it.

Comment: Why don't you splice your deleted item out from $scope array after calling your api for item delete? If you do it so item delete will look reactive

Comment: use something like this `var index = $scope.contacts.indexOf(contactId);` to find it's position in list(add this inside your delete function) and then simply $scope.contacts.splice(index, 1);

Comment: see update 1 @JavaEvgen

Answer (score 1):

i review you code , the problem is here:

```
this.deleteContact = function(contactId) {
  var url = backend_server + "/contacts/" + contactId;
    // actually http delete
    return $http.delete(url)
      .then(function(response) {
        return response;
      }, function(response) {
        alert("Error deleting this contact.");
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

if you have service to manage your contact use there to call your server to delete the contact.

the reason you cannot delete without refresh is:

- your delete from DB but not from angular array.
- must review (update the scope (array))

your code is hard to read , i have suggestion for you, using:

- broserfy , watchify
- lodash
- and backen use mvc

Answer (score 0):

You delete it remotely but not locally. So you can see result only after refreshing (only after you requesting updated data from server). You need to update your local contacts after you succeed on server side.

```
$scope.deleteContact = function(contactId) {
  Contacts.deleteContact(contactId).then(function(data){

    ...

    //DELETE YOU LOCAL CONTACT HERE

    ...

    $location.path("/");
  });

}
```

I didn't look deeply into your code, so I can't say how exactly you should do it, but as I see you keep your local contacts in `$scope.contacts` in your `ListController`.